# Left Anti join not consider null as duplicate values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have tow tables and i want to read only unique records from source table both the table has null values.

```
source table:

name| age| degree| dept    
aaa | 20| ece |null
bbb |20 |it |null
ccc |30 |mech| null

target table


name| age |degree |dept
aaa  |20| ece |null
bbb |20 |it| null
```

soruce_df.join(target_df,seq("name","age","degree"),"leftanti") - >working

soruce_df.join(target_df,seq("name","age","degree","dept"),"leftanti") ->Not working

```
Now i need to pick only 3rd record from source ,

 If i use name ,age ,degree   as my joining key , it's working as expected

But when i include dept it's picking all the records from source table.

Please help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Go for Equality test that is safe for null values.

```scala
    soruce_df.join(target_df, soruce_df("name") <=> target_df("name") && soruce_df("age") <=> target_df("age") &&
      soruce_df("degree") <=> target_df("degree") && soruce_df("dept") <=> target_df("dept")
      ,"leftanti").show(false)

    /**
      * +----+---+------+----+
      * |name|age|degree|dept|
      * +----+---+------+----+
      * |ccc |30 |mech  |null|
      * +----+---+------+----+
      */
```

In python, replace `<=>` with method call `eqNullSafe` as below sample-

```py
df1.join(df2, df1["value"].eqNullSafe(df2["value"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

spark provides null-safe equal operator to handle this scenario.  had faced simillar scenario where duplicate records were getting inserted because one column was having null.
null == null  returns null
null <=> null returns false
see the documentation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-null-semantics.html